# rake routes fails even when app loads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

When running `bundle exec rake routes` in my app directory I get the following error:

```
~/Dropbox/code/mcsl2 /master ! ()> bundle exec rake routes
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- app/controllers/api/provider_controller.rb
```

The file does in fact exist, and the app even loads when running `rails s`.

Any suggestions on how to track down this error?

EDIT: Here's the relevant part of routes.rb

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :provider do
    post 'authenticate'
    namespace :customer do
      get '/', :to => 'customer#index'
      post '/', :to => 'customer#create'
      get '/:id', :to => 'customer#show'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you check that *app/controllers/api/provider_controller.rb* exists? And if it does, please post route definitions related to this controller.

Comment: @Lukas Stejskal, yep. It's there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had an issue with the installation of rails. changing my Gemfile back to 3.0.5 for rails (`gem 'rails', '3.0.5'`) running `bundle update && bundle install`, then setting the Rails gem back to 3.0.9 (`gem 'rails', '3.0.9'`), and running `bundle update && bundle install` again fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post your route file to help us out but may be it has to do with the file being called from app/controllers/api/provider_controller.rb as opposed to to app/controllers/provider_controller.rb

The difference is in the extra api folder.

Comment: The file structure does include the API folder. The pathing is correct. Everything works as expected, EXCEPT rake routes.

Answer (score 0):

`Provider` is not a namespace, it's a resource, an actual controller. Try this:

```
namespace :api do
  resources :providers do
    post 'authenticate'
    ... 
  end
end
```

Comment: I would normally agree with you, however, the current way IS working correctly. I.E, requests to /api/provider/authenticate and /api/provider/customer/find work just fine.

Comment: Well, 'rake routes' doesn't work :). And the app should work even after you change it. BTW :customer should be resource (not namespace) as well.

Answer (score -1):

I know this sounds funny but have you tried turning it off and on again.. literally. I use aptana studio 3 for my rails and im come across the odd time where the studio "forgets" where everything is, at one point it even forgot the bash. Either shut it down and open the IDE again or uninstall it and reinstall. Hopes that works

Comment: I have rebooted. I just use TextMate and a console, so there's not much that can get screwed up!